# C# compare 2 days , minutes are not properly compared

Tags: c#, datetime

I have this confusion of compare 2 days, minutes are not properly compared.
I'm developing email sending too with WPF and have a timer added to it
and in the calling method, I have compared 2 dates with time

```
private void CallTimer()
        {
            try
            {
 
                DateTime lastSendDate = DateTime.Now;  
                int afterDays = 0;  
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => {
 
                    afterDays = int.Parse(txtDays.Text); 
                lastSendDate = clsDb.LastSendTime;              

                DateTime timStr = DateTime.Now.AddDays(afterDays);
 
                    DateTime nowTime = DateTime.Now;

                int days = (timStr - lastSendDate).Days;
                int hrs = (timStr - lastSendDate).Hours;
                int min = (timStr - lastSendDate).Minutes;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("timStr : " + timStr + " lastSendDate : " + lastSendDate);
 
                    if (days == 0 && hrs == 0 && min == 0)
                    { 
                        ....
                    }
                }));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ....
            }
        }
```

when I print a message in the output window, even if there is one-minute difference the if statement becomes true (if (days == 0 && hrs == 0 && min == 0))

**exact values I see this behavior**
debugging details
timStr : 12/10/2020 11:34:44 AM lastSendDate : 12/10/2020 11:35:00 AM

**desired behavior**

timStr : 12/10/2020 11:35:00 AM lastSendDate : 12/10/2020 11:35:00 AM

**what would be the possible reason, any advice to improve the code ?**

is it because of I'm backdating the Lap , clean and rebuild to run the solution?

Comment: As a note, instead of using Dispatcher.Invoke in the callback of a System.Timers.Timer, better use a DispatcherTimer. Its Tick handler is already called in the thread in which the timer was created.

Comment: @Clemens you mean to use DispatcherTimer and dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick; to call , sure , but will it make the output as expected?

Comment: No idea, I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Clemens I'm trying to compare 2 days and if success send mails, even the minute value is not properly compared, yet the condition becomes true

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] question to provide exact values where you see this behavior. Just 3 lines - 2 for date/time creation and one for condition is all that is needed to show the problem.

Comment: Having two DateTime values `12/10/2020 11:34:44 AM` and `12/10/2020 11:35:00 AM` doesn't mean that there is at least a whole minute between them - you have to consider the seconds of each time value as well. Depending on your requirements, you might want to consider something like `(DT2 - DT1).TotalSeconds() > 60` instead.

Answer (score 2):

please be aware that such times should not be compared directly. if you take the time 2 times, it is impossible that the time is identical.
If you compare just minutes, seconds etc, you might fall into rounding issues.
a better comparisson would be

```
 DateTime timStr = DateTime.Now.AddDays(afterDays);
 
 double timeDiff = (timStr - lastSendDate).TotalSeconds;
 if(timeDiff < 0) ....
```